# Problem with ligatures not copying and pasting correctly with newcomputermodern and LuaLaTeX

Tags: fonts, luatex, ligatures

Using Latin Modern (via `lmodern`), this word copies fine: Verlagsgesellschaft.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
Verlagsgesellschaft
\end{document}
```

However, if I instead use `newcomputermodern` I instead get Verlagsgesellscha�, an obvious issue with the ligature. Is it possible to fix this?

MNEW:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newcomputermodern}

\begin{document}
Verlagsgesellschaft
\end{document}
```

The standard solution to copy/paste errors is to add

```
\input{glyphtounicode}
\pdfgentounicode=1
```

but that doesn't work on LuaLaTeX. Is there an equivalent? Failing that, I've been told one of the powers of LuaLaTeX is you can make your own font on the fly, pulling glyphs from elsewhere. If there is a fundamental problem with newcomputermodern could I instead pull those glyphs from say, `lmodern` or `cfr-lm`, or even use one of those for everything except the upright Greek letters?

(Compiled with LuaLaTeX and tested with SumatraPDF v3.1.2 and Adobe Acrobat Reader DC Version 2020.013.20074 and I updated TeXLive 2020 today, 2020-12-30. Information included as previous questions on this topic have come down to out of date versions of various font of pieces of software)

Comment: I can replicate this issue on an up-to-date MacTeX2020 system. I find it very curious that a font which, by its very name, claims to be a Computer Modern clone would provide ligatures -- ft and fft -- that do not exist in Computer Modern.

Comment: Not sure if you're using the `newcomputermodern` package (instead of Latin Modern) *because* it offers the `ft` and `fft` ligatures (and maybe other ligatures too, I don't know). If you're not wedded to the idea of having ft and fft ligatures in your document, you could load the `selnolig` package and issue the instruction `\nolig{ft}{f|t}` to suppress `ft` (and `fft`) ligatures *globally*.

Comment: With XeLaTeX the ligature is correctly copied as “ft”. If I use Libertinus Serif, the ft ligature is correctly copied also with LuaLaTeX. Possibly some missing declaration in the font.

Comment: You can use harfbuzz, it recognize the ligature and setup the right ToUnicode (\defaultfontfeatures{Renderer=Harfbuzz}). Beside this you could report at the luaotfload github. Then we can check if it is a problem with the font or the fontloader.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Can you post a link to that so I can do it?

Comment: @Mico I just spent several days getting my document moved over so I could use the upright Greek alphabet from newcomputermodern. I could move to another package as long as it has that feature, or I could just pull the needed characters from it.

Comment: I already discussed it with Marcel, he said that the font is the problem--it doesn't provide sensible names to the ligatures-- and he will notify the author. Use harfbuzz in the meantime, that should work ok.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hi everybody and Happy New Year. Indeed Marcel contacted me and with the information he provided (for which I thank him), I fixed the fonts. The fonts (newcomputermodern) have been re-uploaded to CTAN and should be available on mirrors in the next 24 hours. The corrected version is Version 2.34.

Comment: And here I was about to look up how to use Harfbuzz! Thank you!

Comment: Also, if I find other errors what is the best way to report those bugs?

Comment: (Several comments deleted; LaTeX was finding the version I installed in Windows, not the updated version)

Comment: You can contact me by email (found in the documentation)